# $route doesnt work with search url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My route example:

```
angular.module('test', [], function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pageOne.html',
    controller: ControllerOne
}).when('/?:foo, { templateUrl: '
pageTwo.html ', controller: ControllerTwo });`
```

But if I load page like http://example.com/?someFoo my route doesn't load ControllerTwo, it load ControllerOne. What I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported by Angular. Check out https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/5l4bbnWp18M/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I think the format is not correct.

```
angular.module('test', [], function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pageOne.html',
    controller: 'ControllerOne'
}).when('/foo/:foo', { templateUrl: '
pageTwo.html ', controller: 'ControllerTwo' });
```

and load page like http://example.com/#/foo/someFoo

I would suggest you to have

```
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/nosuchpage.html'})
```

Then you will know if your link is wrong.

Comment: Yes it's work good, but I need url with /?foo because app search matches in json file

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass controller names as strings

This works

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[],function($routeProvider) {        

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{templateUrl:'home.html'})
        .when('/page1',{templateUrl:'page1.html', controller:'ctrl1'})
        .when('/page2',{templateUrl:'page2.html', controller:'ctrl2'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});

});

function ctrl1($scope){
    $scope.something = 'Hello from page 1';
}
function ctrl2($scope){
    $scope.something = 'Hello from page 2';
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/T2TWB/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my case url must be /?foo. I use $location.search() method.